# What does "x : {0}" means exactly?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FloatConversion
{ 
    class MainApp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float a = 69.6875f;
            Console.WriteLine("a : {0}", a);

            double b = (double)a;
            Console.WriteLine("b : {0}", b);

            Console.WriteLine("69.6875 == b : {0}", 69.6875 == b);

            float x = 0.1f;
            Console.WriteLine("x : {0}", x);

            double y = (double)x;
            Console.WriteLine("y : {0}", y);

            Console.WriteLine("0.1 == y : {0}", 0.1 == y);



            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I just started learning C#. As a Newbie, I was wondering that what `a : {0}` means in `Console.WriteLine()` method.

similarly, what does `69.6875 == b : {0}` mean? how can it be displayed as a boolean?

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Check [String.Format Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) which is exactly what `Console.WriteLine` is doing

Answer (score 2):

`{}` is used to format your string, value inside `{}` shows index of argument which we are passing in `Console.WriteLine`, followed by string.

In your case, in first `Console.WriteLine()`, {0} will be replaced with value of argument `a`(which you passed after "a:{0}").

Here you can get detailed description of String format: [MSDN string format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: oh I see. Thank u a lot!!@

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as a accepted